# jquery mobile app - how to login and store PHP sessions

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am having difficulty creating sessions for my mobile application that is written in JQuery.  I want my application to check to see whether a user session exists, if not it redirects user to a login form.  I use ajax to check the login credentials and the user details are returned in JSON format.

How can I store these JSON variables in a session so that I can access these within my app?

```
function ajaxPost(LoadUrl, redirect) {
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: LoadUrl, 
            data: "email=" + $("#email").val() + "&pw=" + $("#pw").val(),
            complete: function(xhr, statusText){ 
                if (xhr.status == 401){     
                    alert('Unauthorised');
                } 
        } ,

        success:function(response){ 
                if(redirect != null){
                    alert(response);
                    <? 
                    //session_start(); 
                    //$_SESSION['user'] = $response;  // this is JSON: {"id":"45454","name":"Joe Blog","username":"joebloguser"} 
                    ?>
                   app.navigate(redirect);

                }
            }
    });                 
}
```

I have commented out the PHP code that starts the PHP session as this seems to start a session whether or not the ajax call is made, therefore there is always a $_SESSION set, which I obviously do not want.  Can anyone advise on the best way to proceed with this?

Comment: You need to pass async : false at $.ajax to block the code until the request was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put php like that between your javascript, it is run at the moment the page is first loaded (before any javascript is run...) so that will not work.

You need to move your session logic to your `loadUrl` script; verify the login there and start the session if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach this problem (the problem being the immediate communication between an embedded JS script and the PHP data that resides on the server side)

One method would be to simply echo the JSON string into a hidden element if it is present in the session, and then use jquery to fetch and parse it into an object literal if it is present.

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['some_var'])) {
?>
<div id="#jsondata">
<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['some_var']); ?>
</div>
```

JS

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse($('#jsondata').html());
```

Since PHP is going to output this data immediately, it will be rendered into the DOM when PHP finishes outputing to the browser, and when JQuery fires, it will be present to be read.  Obviously this exposes your data structure in the source code, so that is something to consider when utilizing this approach.

Another would be to have a PHP endpoint that outputs the user data if present, mimetyped as json, and a failure value if there is no user session, and have the JS guide the experience based of the output value:

PHP:

```
//in some accessible url
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['some_var'])){
  $data = array('flag'=>1,'obj'=>$_SESSION['some_var']);
}else{
  $data = array('flag'=>0);
}
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

You could then just ajax for this at page load like in your given example and check the flag value for your redirect.

You generally need to design these kinds of things with one universal approach to the problem in mind, since it's going to need to be replicated universally across authed pages.  Do you really need to have authetication checked in the client-side, or can you have the fork for auth manipulated by the server side code (Perhaps by selectively including javascript/template files.)  It's best to think about what's universally applicable for your purposes.